# How do we replace spaces with dashes in a permalink that Autoroute generates from a pattern?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I would like to generate the following URL for a 'My Type' content type.

> mywebsite.com/my-type/some-item

I have tried the following patterns:

- `{Content.ContentType}/{Content.Slug}` : `My Type/some-item`
- `{Content.ContentType.Slug}/{Content.Slug}` : `some-item`
- `{Content.ContentType.Text.Slug}/{Content.Slug}` : `some-item`
- `{Text.Slug}{Content.ContentType}/{Content.Slug}` : `My Type/some-item`

Comment: Is the content type unknown at the time you configure autoroute?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy No. The content type is known, so my solution has been to hard code the replacement of spaces with dashes.

Comment: I don't see any problem with that. Don't make things more complicated than they need to be.